# What does it mean when Docker is simultaneously run in interactive and detatched modess

Tags: docker

I'm new to Docker and came across this confusing (to me) command in one of the Docker online manuals (https://docs.docker.com/storage/bind-mounts/):

```
 $ docker run -d \
  -it \
  --name devtest \
  --mount type=bind,source="$(pwd)"/target,target=/app,readonly \
  nginx:latest
```

What I found confusing was the use of both the `-it` flag and the `-d` flag. I thought `-d` means to run the container in the background, but `-it` means to allow the user to interact with the container via the current shell. What does it mean that *both* flags are present? What am I not understanding here?

Comment: Your intuition is correct - it doesn't really make sense to have both flags. Testing locally, it looks like it just detaches immediately and runs as if `-it` was not there.

Where might actually matter is in a command like `docker run -d -it alpine sh` which will open an interactive `sh` session and immediately detach from it. As opposed to `docker run -d alpine sh` which will just run `sh` and detach and then stop since `sh` doesn't stay alive without a session.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `-i` and `-t` flags influence how stdin and stdout are connected, even in the presence of the `-d` flag. Furthermore, you can always attach to a container in the future using the `docker attach` command.

Consider: If I try to start an interactive shell without passing `-i`...

```
$ docker run -d --name demo alpine sh
```

...the container will exit immediately, because stdin is closed. If I want to run that detached, I need:

```
$ docker run -itd --name demo alpine sh
```

This allows me to attach to the container in the future and interact with the shell:

```
$ docker attach demo
/ #
```

Comment: -OK so '-d' makes docker run in the background, '-i' keeps a pipe to stdin open, in case I decide to attach to the container, and similarly, '-t' keeps a pipe to stdout open, also in case I decide to attach to the container....?

Comment: `-t` makes the pipe to stdin be connected to a tty.

Comment: Without `-t`, for example, you wouldn't have a shell prompt because the shell would assume it's not an interactive session.